# Why does Progress go back to the initial screen after a session crash?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Hello all and thanks for viewing this question,

I have a program that users get access to via a login screen. Once the user's credentials have been validated on the login screen, the main program is called (from the login screen) and the login screen disappears. All good. However, if the session crashes (or I press CTRL-PAUSE), the main program is terminated and I end up at the initial login screen. I'd have assumed that after a session crash, Progress (11.4) should take me back to the OS (Windows Server 2012), but not back to the initial screen. I have tried placing QUIT in different areas of the program, but Progress still takes me back to the initial screen, while I need it to quit completely. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe I have found a way to quit the initial login screen when this appears as the result of a session crash, by using the the ETIME function. Thanks again, Mike for your response.

Comment: Why aren’t you simply catching and handling the error and then quitting as Mike suggested if that’s what you want to do? Whatever it is that you are doing with ETIME is going to confuse the daylights out of the next programmer to come along.

Comment: Hi Tom, the error is related to a QXtend crash; the programmers in charge of QXtend have been unable to find its cause. Once QXtend takes over I can't control the program. The ETIME function allows me to quit the program, rather than leaving a crashed session with a locked table.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

It's the AVM's default behavior to rerun the startup procedure after a STOP condition has occurred that was not handled.

You can add an

```
ON STOP UNDO, RETURN "stopped" .
```

option to a DO, FOR or REPEAT block close where your "crash" happens. Then the calling procedure could check for the RETURN-VALUE of "stopped".

Assuming you are on a recent version (OpenEdge 12.x), you can also use CATCH Blocks for Progress.Lang.Stop:

```
CATCH stopcon AS Progress.Lang.Stop:
    QUIT.
END CATCH.
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, Mike! The session crash could occur in many different programs (due to an external interface). Would there any way of finding out if the login screen is starting from a fresh session or a crashed one (besides the use of a flag)? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your use of the word "crashed" is very, very confusing. If your session actually "crashes" in the usual sense that _progres (or prowin if this is Windows) terminates, then you would not have any locked records remaining. You would also have a protrace file that would help you to identify where the issue occurs.

Incidentally, you could add error logging to the client startup to determine where the errors that QXtend cannot find are occurring:

```
_progres dbname -p startup.p -clientlog logname.log
```

You have not shared any code so I can only guess but, presumably, you are running your login program via the -p startup parameter.

Correct me if I am wrong but something along these lines:

```
_progres dbname -p startup.p
```

The startup program then runs whatever it runs to get you logged in and run the application. Maybe something like this:

```
/* startup.p
 */

message "(re)starting!".
pause.

run value( "login.p" ).

run value( "stuff.p" ).

message "all done".
pause.

quit.
```

And:

```
/* login.p
 */

message "hello, logging in!". 
pause.

return.
```

Along with:

```
/* stuff.p  
 */

message "hello, doing stuff!".
pause.

run value( "notthere.p" ).
   
message "hello, doing more stuff!".
pause.

return.
```

At some point an error occurs (you seem to want to call this a "crash"). I have arranged for a serious error to occur when stuff.p tries to "run notthere.p". So if you run my example you will see the behavior that you have described - your session "crashes", the startup procedure re-runs, and you get to the login screen again.

To change that and trap the error simply wrap a "DO ON STOP" around the RUN statements. Like this:

```
/* startup.p
 */

message "(re)starting!".
pause.

do on error undo,  leave
   on endkey undo, leave
   on stop undo,   leave
   on quit undo,   leave:  /* "leave", exits this block when one of the named conditions arises */ 

  run value( "login.p" ).

  run value( "stuff.p" ).

  /* we just leave because we finished normally */

end.

message "all done".
pause.

quit.
```

You mention QXtend so I am guessing that MFG/Pro is involved. If you cannot directly modify the MFG/Pro startup procedure (as I recall that would be "-p mfg.p") just adapt the code above to be a "shim" that runs mfg.p from within the "DO ON STOP..." block.

Comment: Thanks for your very comprehensive explanation, Tom. From my program I call a QXtend procedure to update a record in QAD. When the server that processes QXtend calls is too busy, it crashes, meaning the Progress session that is running there stops working and exits to the OS. When that occurs, my program goes back to the login screen. I'll try your suggestions and I'll see how I go. Thanks again.